# Python how to select specific cells on excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I have an excel here as shown in this picture:

[image]

I am using pandas to read my excel file and it is working fine, this code below can print all the data in my excel:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('alpha.csv')

print(df)
```

I want to get the values from C2 cell to H9 cell which month is **October** and day is **Monday** only. And I want to store these values in my python array below:

```
mynumbers= []
```

but I am not sure how should I do it, can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider slicing your dataframe and then using `.values` to story them. If you want them as a list, then you can use `to_list()`:

First transform the Date column to a datetime:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],dayfirst=True,infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Then, slice and return the values for the Column `Number 2`

```
mynumbers = df[(df['Date'].dt.month == 10) & \
               (df['Date'].dt.weekday == 0)]['Column 2'].values.tolist()
```

Assigning the following values to `mynumbers`:

```
[11,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

A first step would be to convert your Date column to datetime objects

```
import datetime

myDate = "10-11-22"
myDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(myDate, '%d-%m-%y')
```

Then using myDate.month and myDate.weekday() you can select for mondays in October